# Adding class to menu item in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have menu with items. I want to add to  tag class with name "name". I try to use:

```
var element = document.getElementById('myElement');
element.classList.add('myClass');
```

But the  tag doesn't have any ID or class.

It's even possible with Javascript?

```
<ul id="menu-main">
   <li id="menu-item">
      <a href="#">ODKAZ</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If the parent element has id (as your example) find the parent and navigate to [children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) to add the class. Although there is already a field for css-class for menu items in WordPress admin.

Comment: @Esko

Yes, it is but it's for <li>item, not <a>

Comment: And what are you using the class for? If you want to style the child a-element in css just do .myClass a { font-size: 2em}

Comment: I need to add to <a> tag class called "js-target-scroll" because of onepage menu. But don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to add the class with javascript, you can do:

```js
var element = document.getElementById('menu-item');
element.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].classList.add('js-target-scroll');
```

```html
<ul id="menu-main">
  <li id="menu-item">
    <a href="#">ODKAZ</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But beware that the "onemenu" you are talking about is looking for this css-class and if your own script is not run before that, this won't work since the class is not yet added.

If it's your own theme you are developing, you can add the css-class server side with custom [walker](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker).

Comment: Thanks, sadly, doesn't work because of:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null
at element.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].classList.add('js-target-scroll');

Comment: Are you using the same id's provided in the example code? @PatrikŠtolba

Comment: @PatrikŠtolba it only means that there is no element with id ***menu-item*** in your html, or you are trying to run the code before that part is rendered by the browser.

Comment: I put this script before footer and now it's working, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the class for all menu item anchor tags, you can use the code below. If not, use what Esko has suggested in his answer and comments.

```js
var menuItemLinks = document.querySelectorAll("#menu-main li a");

menuItemLinks.forEach(function(element) {
  element.classList.add("myClass");
});
```

```html
<ul id="menu-main">
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```